# Powershell: script won't run in parallel

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

I have the following script. It will run without a problem when it is not in parallel. But when I add `-Parallel` it throws all kinds of errors. The primary error seems to relate to `Cannot index into a null array`. I using PS 7.3.3. Any suggestions?

### Non-parallel portion of script (start of script)

```
$fileList=(get-childitem -filter *.tif -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match '^[0-9]{3} (B|F) [A-Z]{2} ..K..b [0-9]{2}.*'}).Name
$fileNumbers=($fileList.Substring(0,3) | Sort-Object | Get-Unique)

$fileArr=New-Object 'Object[,]' $fileNumbers.length,5

for ($i=0; $i -lt $fileNumbers.length; $i++) {
    $fileArr[$i,0]=$fileNumbers[$i]
    
    $iStr="{0:d3}" -f ($i+1)

    $backFullName=@()
    $backName=@()
    $frontFullName=@()

    $backFullName+=(Get-ChildItem -filter "$iStr B *.tif" -recurse | Sort-Object).FullName
    $frontFullName+=(Get-ChildItem -filter "$iStr F CC*.tif" -recurse | Sort-Object).FullName
    $backName+=(Get-ChildItem -filter "$iStr B*.tif" -recurse | Sort-Object).Name
    $frontName+=(Get-ChildItem -filter "$iStr F CC*.tif" -recurse | Sort-Object).Name


    if ($backName[0] -eq $null) {
        $backLabel=$null
    }
    else {
        $backLabel=("BRP "+$backName[0].Substring(16,2)+" "+$istr)
    }

    if ($frontName[0] -eq $null) {
        $frontLabel=$null
    }
    else {
        $frontLabel=("BRP "+$frontName[0].Substring(16,2)+" "+$istr)
    }

    $fileArr[$i,1]=$backFullName[0]
    $fileArr[$i,2]=$frontFullName[0]
    $fileArr[$i,3]=$backLabel
    $fileArr[$i,4]=$frontLabel
}
```

---

### Parallel portion of the script (second half of script)

```
    0..($fileNumbers.length-1) | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    if ($using::fileArr[$_,3] -eq $null -and $using::fileArr[$_,4] -ne $null) {
        $label=$using::fileArr[$_,4]
    }
    elseif ($using::fileArr[$_,3] -ne $null -and $using::fileArr[$_,4] -eq $null) {
        $label=$using::fileArr[$_,3]        
    }
    else {
        $label=$using::fileArr[$_,3]        
    }

    $locationA=Get-Random

    Convert +append $using::fileArr[$_,2] $using::fileArr[$_,1] x:\$locationA.jpg
    $height=[string](([int](identify -format "%h" x:\$locationA.jpg)+400))
    $width=(identify -format "%w" x:\$locationA.jpg)
    $halfWidth=([int]$width*.4)
    $dimensions=$width+"x"+$height

    $locationB=Get-Random

    convert x:\$locationA.jpg -gravity north -extent $dimensions x:\$locationB.jpg

    $str="text $halfWidth,50 '$label'"

    convert  x:\$locationB.jpg -pointsize 300  -gravity southwest -draw "$str" x:\$label.jpg
    Remove-Item x:\$locationA.jpg
    Remove-Item x:\$locationB.jpg

} -ThrottleLimit 12
```

Comment: This question belongs on Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks, I'll repost.

Comment: The error message should include a line number.

Comment: the error, `cannot index into a null array` first appears in the second line of the parallel block: `if ($using::fileArr[$_,3] -eq $null -and $using::fileArr[$_,4] -ne $null)`. I can only assume it is referring to `$using::fileArr`. However, this array is populated correctly before entering the parallel block. As I said, it will execute correctly when not in parallel (with `$using::fileArr` changed back to `$fileArr`.

Comment: @Brian [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment with unformatted errors that are difficult to read. Don’t repost this question. This question will be migrated once it receives enough votes. Reposting questions at multiple communities is how users end of being question banned

Comment: Brian, don't repost. We can move the question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the "don't repost" until after I had reposted. I will take that into consideration in the future.